# Trying to compile and launch an open source android app, getting the following error: Error inflating class com.android.deskclock.widget.RtlViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, open-source, android-sdk-2.3

I'm trying to compile the "deskclock" application from Android, source found here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/

I've created a new project in the Android SDK, added the files, and updated the references to match the new package name. The application will compile, and install on the emulator, but upon launch it crashes almost immediately with the following error:

```
05-16 20:53:37.927 2628-2628/com.mycompanyname.builtinclock E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.mycompanyname.builtinclock, PID: 2628
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompanyname.builtinclock/com.mycompanyname.builtinclock.deskclock.DeskClock}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #50: Binary XML file line #50: Error inflating class com.android.deskclock.widget.RtlViewPager
```

I can't seem to find what is causing this to happen. I've cleaned and rebuilt the project to no effect.

The only major changes I've made to the above source, is to change the company name to match the new package name and update that in each file that references locations to get rid of all the errors it gave before it would compile.

The other big change, was to the build.gradle file, where I removed the datetimepicker entry(couldn't figure out how to get that to compile) and I re-added the appcompat dependencies on the dependencies screen instead.

If someone can help me, by either pointing out what's wrong with the code, or showing me a better way to compile that package, I would be super grateful! My apologies if this comes off as a dumb question.

See below for the two files that were changed.

Here is the gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mycompanyname.builtinclock"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}


dependencies {

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.4.0'
}
```

And here is the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!--
  Copyright (C) 2015 The Android Open Source Project

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or      implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
  -->

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompanyname.builtinclock"
    android:versionCode="410" android:versionName="4.1.0">

<original-package android:name="com.android.alarmclock" />
<original-package android:name="com.android.deskclock" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<!-- WRITE_SETTINGS is required to record the upcoming alarm prior to L -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<!-- READ_PHONE_STATE is required to determine when a phone call exists prior to M -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<!-- READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is required to play custom ringtones from the SD card prior to M -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application android:label="@string/app_label"
             android:name=".deskclock.DeskClockApplication"
             android:allowBackup="true"
             android:backupAgent=".deskclock.DeskClockBackupAgent"
             android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_scheme"
             android:fullBackupOnly="true"
             android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
             android:requiredForAllUsers="true"
             android:supportsRtl="true">

    <provider android:name=".deskclock.provider.ClockProvider"
            android:authorities="com.android.mycompanyname.deskclock"
            android:exported="false" />

    <activity android:name=".deskclock.DeskClock"
            android:label="@string/app_label"
            android:theme="@style/DeskClockTheme"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_alarmclock"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity-alias android:name="DockClock"
            android:targetActivity=".deskclock.DeskClock"
            android:label="@string/app_label"
            android:theme="@style/DeskClockTheme"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_alarmclock"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:enabled="@bool/config_dockAppEnabled"
            >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DESK_DOCK" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>

    <activity android:name=".deskclock.settings.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/settings"
            android:theme="@style/SettingsTheme"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".deskclock.worldclock.CitySelectionActivity"
            android:label="@string/cities_activity_title"
            android:theme="@style/CitiesTheme"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:excludeFromRecents="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".deskclock.alarms.AlarmActivity"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:theme="@style/AlarmAlertFullScreenTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true" />

    <activity android:name=".deskclock.ScreensaverActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/ScreensaverActivityTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|keyboard" />

    <receiver android:name=".deskclock.alarms.AlarmStateManager"
              android:exported="false">
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".deskclock.alarms.AlarmService"
             android:exported="false">
    </service>

    <activity android:name=".deskclock.HandleApiCalls"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:permission="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"
            android:taskAffinity="">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_ALARM" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DISMISS_ALARM" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SNOOZE_ALARM" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SHOW_ALARMS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_TIMER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity-alias android:name="HandleSetAlarm"
        android:targetActivity=".deskclock.HandleApiCalls"
        android:exported="true">
    </activity-alias>

    <activity android:name=".deskclock.HandleDeskClockApiCalls"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:permission="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"
        android:taskAffinity="">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.action.SHOW_CLOCK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.action.ADD_CLOCK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.action.DELETE_CLOCK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.action.START_TIMER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.action.RESET_TIMER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.action.PAUSE_TIMER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.action.SHOW_TIMERS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.action.DELETE_TIMER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.action.SHOW_STOPWATCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.action.START_STOPWATCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.action.PAUSE_STOPWATCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.action.LAP_STOPWATCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.action.RESET_STOPWATCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="deskclock.AlarmInitReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.mycompanyname.builtinclock.alarmclock.AnalogAppWidgetProvider"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_alarmclock"
        android:label="@string/analog_gadget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.oldName"
            android:value="com.android.deskclock.AnalogAppWidgetProvider"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/analog_appwidget"/>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.mycompanyname.builtinclock.alarmclock.DigitalAppWidgetProvider"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_alarmclock"
        android:label="@string/digital_gadget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.DIGITAL_WIDGET_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.ON_QUARTER_HOUR"/>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.NEXT_ALARM_CLOCK_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/digital_appwidget"/>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.mycompanyname.builtinclock.alarmclock.DigitalAppWidgetService"
         android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS"
         android:exported="false" />

    <!-- Dream (screensaver) implementation -->
    <service android:name="deskclock.Screensaver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_label"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DREAM_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.dreams.DreamService" />
            <action android:name="android.app.action.NEXT_ALARM_CLOCK_CHANGED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.dream"
            android:resource="@xml/dream_info" />
    </service>

    <!-- Settings activity for screensaver -->
    <activity android:name=".deskclock.settings.ScreensaverSettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/screensaver_settings"
            android:theme="@style/SettingsTheme"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="true"
            >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".deskclock.AlarmSelectionActivity"
        android:label="@string/dismiss_alarm"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar"/>

    <!-- This activity displays only the timers that have expired with only a reset button
     present. This makes the activity appropriate for display above the lock screen so that
     users have the limited ability to silence expired timers but nothing else. -->
    <activity android:name=".deskclock.timer.ExpiredTimersActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:theme="@style/ExpiredTimersActivityTheme"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:configChanges="screenSize|keyboardHidden|keyboard|navigation"/>

    <!-- Legacy broadcast receiver that honors old scheduled timers across app upgrade. -->
    <receiver android:name="deskclock.timer.TimerReceiver"
              android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="times_up" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".deskclock.timer.TimerService"
             android:exported="false"
             android:description="@string/timer_service_desc">
    </service>

    <service android:name=".deskclock.stopwatch.StopwatchService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:description="@string/stopwatch_service_desc">
    </service>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your layout xml file, you are still using the class **com.android.deskclock.widget.RtlViewPager**. As  you changed the package name, you need to change the same in xml file as well

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much!